# Renaming a Folder and create a new folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

My folder structure: C:\example\latest.
I want to check if the subfolder latest already exists or not. If it does, I want to rename it as latest_MMddyyyy and then create a new folder called latest.
If it does not have latest already, then simple create the folder.

This is what I have:

```
param (
    $localPath = "c:\example\latest\"                                                       #"
)

        #Creating a new directory if does not exist
        $newpath = $localPath+"_"+((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
        If (test-path $localPath){
            Rename-Item -path $localpath -newName $newpath
        }
        New-Item -ItemType -type Directory -Force -Path $localPath
```

It is doing two things:

1. Rename my latest folder as _MM-dd-yyyy but I want it to rename as "latest_MM-dd-yyyy"
2. Throw an error: Missing an argument for parameter 'ItemType'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Throws an error: `Missing an argument for parameter 'ItemType'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.`

As [Deadly-Bagel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118524/45375) points out, you're missing an argument to `-ItemType` and instead follow it with *another* parameter, `-Type`, which, in fact, is an *alias* for `-ItemType` - so **removing *either* `-ItemType` *or* `-Type` will work**.

<sup>To find a parameter's aliases, use something like `(Get-Command New-Item).Parameters['ItemType'].Aliases`</sup>

> Renames my latest folder to `_MM-dd-yyyy`, but I want `latest_MM-dd-yyyy`.

- You append the date string directly to `$localPath`, which has a *trailing `\`*, so `$newPath` looks something like `'c:\example\latest\_02-08-2017'`, which is not the intent.
- **Ensuring that `$localPath` has no trailing `\` fixes the problem**, but do note that **`Rename-Item` *generally* only accepts a file/directory *name* as a `-NewName` argument, not a *full path***; you can only get away with a full path if its parent path is the *same* as the input item's - in other words, you can only specify a path if it wouldn't result in a *different location* for the renamed item (you'd need the `Move-Item` cmdlet to achieve that).

  - `Split-Path -Leaf $localPath` offers a convenient way of extracting the *last* path component, whether or not the input path has a trailing `\`.
    In this case: `latest`
  - Alternatively, `$localPath -replace '\\$'` would always return a *path* without a trailing `\`.
    In this case: `c:\example\latest`

If we put it all together:

```powershell
param (
  $localPath = "c:\example\latest\"         #"# generally, consider NOT using a trailing \
)

# Rename preexisting directory, if present.
if (Test-Path $localPath) {
 # Determine the new name: the name of the input dir followed by "_" and a date string.
 # Note the use of a single interpolated string ("...") with 2 embedded subexpressions, 
 # $(...)
 $newName="$(Split-Path -Leaf $localPath)_$((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))"
 Rename-Item -Path $localPath -newName $newName
}

# Recreate the directory ($null = ... suppresses the output).
$null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $localPath
```

Note that if you run this script more than once *on the same day*, you'll get an error on renaming (which could easily be handled).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$localPath = "c:\temp\example\latest"

#remove last backslash
$localPath= [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName("$localPath\")                               #"

#create new path name with timestamp
$newpath ="{0}_{1:MM-dd-yyyy}" -f $localPath, (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

#rename old dir if exist and recreate localpath
Rename-Item -path $localpath -newName $newpath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $localPath
```

Answer (score 2):

```
New-Item -ItemType -type Directory -Force -Path $localPath
```

You're using -ItemType but not providing it a value, use this:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $localPath
```

Answer (score -1):

To  rename a folder, use the command: `Rename-Item` e.g

`Rename-Item` Old_Folder_Name  New_Folder_Name